# How do I search for multiple file types using Bundle.main.path

Tags: ios, swift

At the moment I've got

```
let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: songs[indexPath.row], ofType: "flac")
```

I want to have the audioPath find songs with multiple audio extensions like .mp3, .wav, etc but I can't figure out how to do this?

I looked in the bundle programming guide (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-SW7) but still couldn't figure it out.

Thanks heaps

edit: I know the names of the files, but in a situation where the folder has mp3's and flacs and wav files and all those other extensions, I want the code to be able to play all of those types of audio files and not just one.

edit: maybe this bit of code is also relevant where I tell it to find only flac files (also wasn't sure how to extend this to other audio file types):

```
for song in songPath
    {
        var mySong = song.absoluteString
        if mySong.contains (".flac")
```

Comment: Do you know the names of the files, or is the problem that you want to find _any_ files of the various types?

Comment: I know the names of the files, but in a situation where the folder has mp3's and flacs, I want the code to be able to play both types and not just one.

Comment: sorry for not seeing your comment earlier, I'm new to this site and missed it

Comment: @matt (I think I was meant to type this?)